# Proper way to "append" multi-dimensional numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4d array `x`, for which I want to loop through the first axis, modify that 3d array, and add this modified array to a new 4d array `y`.

I am currently doing something like:

```
xmod = modify(x[0, :, :, :])
y = xmod.reshape(1, x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3])
for i in range(1, x.shape[0]):
    xmod = modify(x[i, :, :, :])
    y = np.vstack((y, xmod))
```

I am guessing there is amuch cleaner to do this. How?

Comment: Python-level loops, and *especially* appending in a loop, are spectacularly slow ways to use NumPy. Can you make `modify` operate in a vectorized manner on all of `x`?

Comment: I would love to, but I don't know if I can. My `modify` is really the resizing of an image: `xmod = scipy.misc.imresize(x[i,:,:,0], 1.3)`. I don't think `imresize` can be vectorized, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to create a blank array of the appropriate final size and then slice-assign the results into it one by one.

Answer (score 2):

If you must act on `x` one submatrix at a time you could do:

```
y = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    y[i,...] = modify(x[i,...])
```

e.g.

```
In [595]: x=np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
In [596]: y=np.zeros_like(x)
In [597]: for i in range(x.shape[0]):
   .....:     y[i,...]=x[i,...]*2
   .....:     
In [598]: y
Out[598]: 
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 4,  6],
        ...
        [40, 42],
        [44, 46]]])
```

appending to lists is generally better than repeatedly 'appending' to arrays:

```
In [599]: y=[]
In [600]: for row in x:
   .....:     y.append(row*2)
   .....: 
In [601]: y=np.array(y)
```

for very large cases you could see if `vstack` (or concatenate axis=0) is faster.  But you have to explicitly add a beginning dimension to the arrays.

```
In [615]: y=[]
In [616]: for row in x:
    y.append((row*2)[None,:])
   .....:     
In [617]: np.vstack(y)
```

Comment: `for subarray in x` and `np.empty_like` would be faster.

Comment: In my first example I'd have to use `for i,row in enumerate(x):`, or may `zip(x,y)`.  In a situation like this I doubt if `empty_like` is that much faster than `zeros_like`.  The iteration takes much more time.